# How to know when a function jQuery has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jQuery and I can't get it done. I have 2 bulletproof vest images. When a button is clicked, 1 will show up. When another is clicked, all vests have to be hidden again first. Now the vests both show up and then 1 disappears.

Here is my example: http://bykwien.nl/soldier/voorbeeld.html

Full preview on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8DPCf/

```
$('#vest1').click(function(){
            $('.vest').addClass('hide', function(){
                $('.vest1').removeClass('hide');
            })
        });

        $('#vest2').click(function(){
            $('.vest').addClass('hide', function(){
                $('.vest2').removeClass('hide');
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the callbacks will make the whole thing work, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8DPCf/1/

```
$('#vest2').click(function(){
    $('.vest').addClass('hide', function(){
        $('.vest2').removeClass('hide');
    })
});
```

becomes

```
$('#vest2').click(function(){
    $('.vest').addClass('hide');
    $('.vest2').removeClass('hide');
});
```

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/), the `addClass` method has no callback parameter, which it also doesn't need because it doesn't do anything asynchronically.

Comment: It does work, but i have the next issue: 1 or 2 divs will show up onClick. If u switch, the vests will both go down a bit. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8DPCf/4/ new live example: http://www.bykwien.nl/soldier2/voorbeeld.html

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Fix**

I don't think you need to use any callback function for this, just do the 2 calls sequentially like so:

```
$('#vest1').click(function(){
    $('.vest').addClass('hide');
    $('.vest1').removeClass('hide');
});

$('#vest2').click(function(){
    $('.vest').addClass('hide');
    $('.vest2').removeClass('hide');
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/J5X9D/)

**Advanced Solution**

In order to make it more generic, allowing for x number of vests you could create a single event handler and determine the vest class using the `id` of the clicked button...

Change your button HTML like so (added class):

```
<div class="item-checkbox vest-button" id="vest1"></div>
<div class="item-checkbox vest-button" id="vest2"></div>
```

And your javascript as follows:

```
//add event to all vest elements, and use this to determine which one is clicked
$('.vest-button').click(function(){
    $('.vest').addClass('hide');
    var className = '.' + $(this).attr("id");
    $(className).removeClass('hide');
});
```

[Here it is in action](http://jsfiddle.net/J5X9D/2/)